# Using Open-Telemetry-Collector as a proxy to collect Prometheus metrics and Loki logs and send to several backend

Tags: open-telemetry-collector

I was wondering if it's possible to use Open Telemetry Collector as a proxy to collect Prometheus metrics and Loki logs and send to several backend.

I understand it's possible in some situation but I'm not sure if it's still possible with my requirements.

Open Telemetry Collector should ideally authenticate client with basic authentication, assign a "tenant" based on the authenticated user, and then send the request to all backend including the tenant for example as the X-Scope-OrgID expected by a Loki backend.

If this is not possbile I can still include a minimal reverse proxy in front of Open Telemetry Collector doing this job, but Open Telemetry Collector should then forward the received Authorization and X-Scope-OrgID headers to all backend.

Is this a feature of involved receivers and exporters?

Note that X-Scope-OrgID is generally not constant and depends on credentials used.